# identified related questions - what to do?

Tags: discussion

I've found that I have already given an answer to a similar or related and duplicated question. What is to do? The following questions are mentioning the same problem - in my opinion - but they are not linked in any way.

[Is reading bass clef by reference to the corresponding position in treble clef a bad learning method?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/79331/is-reading-bass-clef-by-reference-to-the-corresponding-position-in-treble-clef-a)

[How can I learn to read bass clef score more naturally?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/31250/how-can-i-learn-to-read-bass-clef-score-more-naturally)

[Me and the grand staff: how to achieve pacific coexistence](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30596/me-and-the-grand-staff-how-to-achieve-pacific-coexistence)

Shall I comment: this is a duplicate (related question) as commentary.
Shall I copy my answer of the other question.
Shall I answer short and copy the link to the other answer/question.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is answered by the posts on the possible duplicate, please vote to close as duplicate. That's the best way to deal with it.

If you find yourself wanting to post exactly the same answer - they are probably dupes.

Comment: I meant this situation, when we discover 2 or 3 questions and they are maybe older than some years. ( I think normally this shouldn be the case). well, 2 of the 3 above are from this winter ...

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli While there are some aspects of SE that are dependent on the age of the post (like asking OP for clarification six years later), since OP doesn't have to do anything when their question gets put on hold or closed, I think we can probably VTC regardless of age of post. Of course, if it's old enough, it might be the case that that post predates the other!

Answer (score 3):

*(I am not a Moderator)*

User Doktor Mayhem's answer seems to be the final authority on determining the dupes from the poop, but let me address what to do once one determines the status of the questions.

If the two should be dupes, then of course vote to close as a duplicate.

If, after looking at the two posts, you find that they *are not duplicates*, then I recommend that you mention that the two are related in a comment on the question ("Related: [link]"). OP may find some useful information there, and prospective answerers as well.

Also, I wouldn't give a link-only answer if I thought they were duplicates. I'd probably either not answer or summarize what I said earlier and link to it.

Comment: Excellent point - often questions are related but not dupes, so ensuring they are linked helps others follow.